# How do I make the images show the same height? bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

it shows up like that because my photo is not the same size, is there a solution for this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdiDN.jpg)

here is the code:

```
<div class="features_items"><!--features_items-->
    <h2 class="title text-center">Features Items</h2>
        @foreach($products as $product)
        <div class="col-sm-4 h-100">
            <div class="product-image-wrapper ">
                <div class="single-products h-100">
                        <div class="productinfo h-100 text-center">
                            <img src="{{$baseUrl . $product->feature_image_path}}" alt="" />
                            <h2>{{ number_format($product->price )}} VNĐ</h2>
                            <p>{{ $product->name }}</p>
                            <a href="#" 
                                data-url="{{route('addToCart',['id'=> $product->id])}}" 
                                class="btn btn-default add_to_cart">
                                    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                                    Add to cart
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product-overlay">
                            <div class="overlay-content">
                                <h2>{{ number_format($product->price )}} VNĐ</h2>
                                <p>{{ $product->name }}</p>
                                <button 
                                data-url="{{route('addToCart',$product->id)}}" 
                                class="btn btn-default add_to_cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>     
        @endforeach
</div><!--features_items-->
```

Comment: Maybe place the image inside a div and statically set the height of that elements css to the height of your tallest image. This will force the h2 tag down to the bottom of images parent div no matter what height they are. So `<div class="productinfo">`, then place another div around the image inside that div and set its height statically.

Comment: You can use with flexbox it's a single declaration